# Putting GCP cloudrun behind a load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We have a cloud security tool integrated with our GCP organization that recommends putting cloud runs behind load balancers for better network-based access control. Isn't this an overkill cost-wise? also, what's the risk in allowing direct access to these cloud runs if they are originally intended to be public?

Answer (score 3):

It's a usual standard pattern. Costly? about $15 more per month to add a load balancer.

But I agree, adding a Load balancer has strictly no value, but it's an enabler for 3 different features:

- Routing to several service with a single web facing endpoint https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts
- Custom domain and custom certificate https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/ssl-certificates
- Cloud Armor activation for WAF and advanced attack protection https://cloud.google.com/security/products/armor?hl=en

Cloud Armor is especially recommended when you want to make your Cloud Run public.

---

And more thanks to John:

- Static global IP address that you can bind to your registrar.
- Cloud CDN https://cloud.google.com/cdn?hl=en
- mTLS for client authentication https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/mtls
- Custom public port numbers (other than HTTPS 443)

Comment: Good answer. Add 1) Static global IP address. 2) Cloud CDN. 3) mTLS for client authentication. 4) Custom public port numbers (other than HTTPS 443).

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley. mTLS is new, isn't it?

Comment: I don't remember when it was added - at least a year ago.